# amp does not work with bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, amp-html

I am using bootstrap carousel where I have changed the image tag from `img` to `amp-img`. I can see only first image is converted into amp but next image is not. I can see in the console as `img` tag of first image inside the `amp-tag` but second `img` tag is not in `amp-tag`. Please see screenshot of console.

[img tag converted to amp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q9VB.png)
    [image: img tag converted to amp]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/streetcoder/m4md59ok/)

Comment: make a jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: I have added jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

well this is not carousel issue this is something different, check this [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#required-markup) of AMP they exactly describe what setup needed in order to generate amp images perfectly

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <style amp-custom>
    h1 {
      margin: 16px;
    }
  </style>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">




  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <amp-img src="http://mytonic-revamp-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/revamp/s3fs-public/Chat_adapt_English_0.png" alt="..." width="720" height="480"></amp-img>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <amp-img src="http://mytonic-revamp-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/revamp/s3fs-public/Keep-calm-and-fare-well-in-your-exams-New-Website-Article-Carousel_0.jpg" alt="..." width="720" height="480"></amp-img>
        </div>

    </div>


    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

check this out in mobile screens, no snippet or fiddle is able to generate images since content is blocked, you can check your given fiddle's console(use latest version of bootstrap.min.js there),snapshot of your generated images

[image: snapshot of your generated images]